# Is there a more elegant way to do search for max and conversion to Int

Tags: purescript

given the following function

```
maxInt :: Array Number -> Int
maxInt xs = fromMaybe 0 $ join $ fromNumber <$> maximum xs

maxInt [ 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0 ] => 5
```

Is there some a more elegant way to do this? There is a lot of stripping away `Maybe`s

Comment: What `maximum` function is this you're referring to? Evidently none of [the standard ones](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=maximum) – these don't return `Maybe` values (though arguably they should. Also, what is `fromNumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `fromNumber` to the entire input first, then take the maximum of *that* list. This way, all invalid values are converted to `Nothing` first, which `maximum` will ignore.

```
maxInt = fromMaybe 0 . maximum . (map fromNumber)
```

(This works because `Ord a => Maybe a` is an instance of `Ord`; `Nothing` is less than any `Just` value, and `Just` values are ordered by the underlying value.)

This also fixes a potential bug, if `fromNumber (maximum xs) == Nothing`. In that case, `maxInt` would return 0, even if there is some slightly smaller value `y` such that `fromNumber y` is not `Nothing`.

Comment: fromNumber could be expensive. Your bug could be his intended behavior.

Comment: It seems unlikely that *n* calls to `fromNumber` is any more expensive than the work that the `Number` instance of `Ord` specifies to implement `maximum`. I also find it unlikely that the intended maximum of `[Just 5, Nothing]` is supposed to be 0.

Comment: It doesnt exactly answer my question (or rather implicitly with "NO") & the `join` is missing as `maximum . (map fromNumber) :: Maybe (Maybe Int)`. Nevertheless I learned that `maximum` works on `Maybe`s as well. Thats cool

Comment: In general my question was more if the expression could be condensed much much more (which I think it can't). Sometimes I find Haskells/Purescripts orgy of nested `Maybe`s pretty exhausting ;-)

Comment: It might help if you supplied the definition of `Array` and `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to handle that with a default case of 0? If so, you're looking for `maxInt xs = fromMaybe 0 $ fromNumber =<< maximum xs`. If not, keep the Maybe around and do it like `maxInt = fromNumber <=< maximum`.